# R Find matches between a data.table of data and a data.table of random values

Tags: r, data.table

Couldn't come up with good title, hope the following explains what I'm after.  For every row in dtRandom I want to know how many rows in dtFamilies match the criteria of max and min cats and dogs.

```
require(data.table)
dtFamilies <- data.table(Family=c('Smith','Jones','White','Harris'),
                 Dogs=c(7,0,2,1),
                 Cats=c(0,3,0,8))

lowDogs <- min(DT[,Dogs])
highDogs <- max(DT[,Dogs])
lowCats <- min(DT[,Cats])
highCats <- max(DT[,Cats])

set.seed(1)
DogsMin <- sample(lowDogs:highDogs,10,replace = T)
DogsMax <- sample(lowDogs:highDogs,10,replace = T)
CatsMin <- sample(lowCats:highCats,10,replace = T)
CatsMax <- sample(lowCats:highCats,10,replace = T)

dtRandom <- data.table(DogsMin,DogsMax,
                       CatsMin,CatsMax)

dtRandom <- transform(dtRandom,
                 DogsMin = ifelse(DogsMin < DogsMax, DogsMin, DogsMax), DogsMax = ifelse(DogsMax > DogsMin, DogsMax, DogsMin),
                 CatsMin = ifelse(CatsMin < CatsMax, CatsMin, CatsMax), CatsMax = ifelse(CatsMax > CatsMin, CatsMax, CatsMin))


# I now have dtFamilies which is a list of families and the number of dogs and cats that they have.
# I also have dtRandom which has 10 rows of random values for min and max number of pets

# Below obviously does not work
    nrow(DT[Dogs >= DogsMin & Dogs <= DogsMax &
    Cats >= CatsMin & Cats <= CatsMax]))
```

For every row in dtRandom I want to know how many rows in dtFamilies match the criteria of max and min cats and dogs.

I'm new to R and there's lots of functionality I don't know how to apply.  Some guidance is much appreciated.  I have the functionality working using a loop but I keep reading that loops are bad in R and that R methods should be used.

Example of what I want (just an example - this does not match data above):

```
    DogsMin DogsMax CatsMin CatsMax Matches
1:       0       5       3       6    1
2:       6       6       2       3    0
3:       1       7       2       7    2
4:       1       4       4       6    1
5:       6       6       0       7    3
6:       5       6       4       4    0
7:       2       5       4       8    4
8:       2       3       2       4    0
9:       1       5       3       4    1
10:      0       4       1       5    1
```

Comment: You mention a `dtFamilies` table that doesn't appear in the code. You'll want to add that to make the example fully reproducible, preferably also with your expected output.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for `DT[dtRandom, on=.(Dogs >= DogsMin, Dogs <= DogsMax, Cats >= CatsMin, Cats <= CatsMax), .N, by=.EACHI]`, though ..?

Comment: @Frank - thank you.  I updated my question.

Comment: @Frank - yes that did it exactly!  I have no idea how it works so I'll have to spend some time researching this.

Comment: Oh cool, glad to hear it. It's called a non-equi join, a rather new feature. You can find some documentation by typing `?data.table`. The "Videos & Slides" section of the website might also be useful for new features like this (until they're covered in a vignette): http://r-datatable.com

Answer (score 0):

> For every row in dtRandom I want to know how many rows in dtFamilies match the criteria of max and min cats and dogs.

Here's one way:

```
DT[dtRandom, on=.(Dogs >= DogsMin, Dogs <= DogsMax, Cats >= CatsMin, Cats <= CatsMax),
  .N, by=.EACHI]
```

---

*How it works*

To select rows based on inequalities vs variables in another table, we need a non-equi join:

```
DT[dtRandom, on=.(Dogs >= DogsMin, Dogs <= DogsMax, Cats >= CatsMin, Cats <= CatsMax)]
```

To count rows meeting some criteria, we can use `.N`.

With `by=.EACHI` we compute this count for each row of `i` in `x[i, on, j, by=.EACHI]`.

See `?data.table` for more details.